# Getting nextdns working on Manjaro Linux

Tags: networking, dns, arch-linux

I just shifted from xubuntu to manjaro linux and i want to setup nextdns for the system.

I have tried two ways and both of them failed.

#### Try 1

I followed the download instruction as given on the [github
    page](https://github.com/nextdns/nextdns). When i install nextdns i
    see that its starts a server on port 53 ( to i guess forward all DNS
    requests over HTTPS) and changes the `/etc/resolv.conf` to the following

```
    # This file is managed by nextdns.
    #
    # Run "nextdns deactivate" to restore previous configuration.

    nameserver ::1
```

But when I ping `ping www.google.com` it gives me `name or service unknown`. I can ping 8.8.8.8

#### Try 2

Next I tried DNS over TLS using unbound. I read [the arch linux documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unbound) and [this tutorial](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/unbound-tls-forwarding.html).
I just added the following lines to `/etc/unbound/unbound.conf`

```
tls-cert-bundle: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
forward-zone:
    name: "."
    forward-tls-upstream: yes
    forward-addr: <ip4 address>#<nextdns config_id>.dns1.nextdns.io
    forward-addr: <ip6 address>#<nextdns config_id>.dns1.nextdns.io
    forward-addr: <ip4 address>#<nextdns config_id>.dns2.nextdns.io
    forward-addr: <ip6 address>#<nextdns config_id>.dns2.nextdns.io
```

The forwarding addresses are correct (They are given in my nextdns setup page).

I then added `name_servers="::1 127.0.0.1"` to my `/etc/resolvconf.conf` and executed `resolvconf -u` as indicated in the [arch linux documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unbound#Local_DNS_server).
My `/etc/resolv.conf` changes accordingly. 
But i still can't ping domain names.

I don't how to go about troubleshooting this issue. Manjaro is a bit different then ubuntu. Any help will be appreciated.

### Edit

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` is as follows

```
# Name Service Switch configuration file.
# See nsswitch.conf(5) for details.

passwd: files mymachines systemd
group: files mymachines systemd
shadow: files

publickey: files

hosts: files mymachines mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns mdns4 myhostname
networks: files

protocols: files
services: files
ethers: files
rpc: files

netgroup: files
```

Comment: did you check what is `/etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov i added it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other place to check is file `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

for the `hosts` line you can add `dns`:

```
hosts: files dns ....
```

and check again. This file is used to define which source to use when resolve different objects like users, hosts, etc.

Comment: `dns` is already there. Or does the ordering matter ?

Comment: AFAIK if you have records like: ` [NOTFOUND=return]  [!UNAVAIL=return]` you can skip the rest of keywords. So yes, it matters.

Comment: i did move `dns` to after `files` but it still didn't work

Comment: @fboitry to add by hand two nameserver records , one ::1 and one 127.0.0.1. And check if something listen on port 53

Comment: sorry for the late update. I guess i just had to restart for the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` changes to take place. Name resolution is working fine with nextdns cli client. I deleted unbound. I just had to prevent NetworkManager from changing `/etc/resolv.conf`. This i did by editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51784208/stop-network-manager-from-updating-resolv-conf/51785308#51785308)